# concatenation in IPython.display in a notebook using Latex+symbols

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Say I have an expression which I would like to display in LateX form and one which is a result of an analytical calculation where variables like `theta` appear and are pretty printed in the end. I would like to print both in one line. Here an example:

```
from IPython.display import display, Math, Latex
import numpy as np
from sympy import *

init_printing()

# In[1]:
name='\Gamma^'+str(1)+'_{'+str(2)+str(3)+'}'+'='

# In[2]:
theta = symbols('theta')

# In[3]:
display(Math(name),theta)
```

The last command prints `name` in a pretty form (LateX) as well as `theta`. However, a line-break is added which I would like to omit. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to form latex string first. Use sympy.latex() to make string from any printable sympy variable:

```
display(Math(name + latex(theta)))
```

I also wrote simple function with variable number of arguments for such output. No need to wrap variables with latex() here:

```
def prlat(*args):
    str = ''
    for arg in args:
        str += latex(arg)
    display(Math(str))

prlat(name, theta, '= 0')
```